# How can I fetch updated values from user profile edit form?

Tags: forms

I want to check image field length from user edit form, I mean that upload image field accepting more than one image, so i want to validate the number of images to be save / upload into database before going to save in database. And also let me know is any hook is available for upload button.

Answer (score 0):

You'd want to use hook_form_alter
https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7.x

And add your own validate function with something like:

```
$form['#validate'][] = 'my_function_name';
```

Then you can do whatever checks you want in there and then use form_set_error if needed to stop the form submission if required and nothing will get saved

Answer (score 0):

In My case iam using presave hook, after click on submit button presave custom module will activates that time it accepts $edit as one of parameter so you can use $edit to access updated form values 
example:
$edit['field_full_name']['und'][0]['value'] ,
count($edit['field_gallery']['und'])
And it works for me.

Thank you